# How can i add in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript like [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gfkLd8v/) in my webpage for calculation. Here my function is

```
function product2()
{   
    var a2 = document.getElementById("chkBox2").checked;
    var b2 = document.getElementById("chkBox2").value;
    var c2 = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
    var d2 = 0;

    if (a2 == true)
    {
        d2 = b2 * c2/100;
    }
    else
    {
        d2=""
    }
 document.getElementById("total2").value = d2;
}
```

But here i want some different result. I expalin

If `a2 = 1237 and b2 = 13` then result is **160.81** but here i want Result will be 1397.81 Means result(d2) should be plus in a2 AND this total want to display.

How can i do this.
Please help!

Comment: I think forgot to mention C2 ??  value

Comment: Yeah...It is b2 = 1237(Checknox value) and c2 = 13(dropdown value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should be this:

```
function product1(){
    var m = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("check1").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty1").value);
    var z = 0;

    if (m == true){
        z = ((x*y)/100)+x;
        z = "P" + z;
    } else {
        z="P0.00"
    }

    document.getElementById("total1").value = z;
}
```

Here I have used `parseInt` function of javascript to convert it in the integer. This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what u are asking. But if you are asking simply modifying the calculation just modify the formula
d2 = (b2 * c2/100)+b2;

Comment: It is displaying like 160.811237.00